# Modal close when i click on it

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

When user want to leave page, bootstrap 4 modal will pop up, but when i click on it , modal close, how can i prevent it?

I have tried many things from this forum but it didnt worked for me. I am out of ideas.

This is my code:

```
<div class="modal" id="ouibounce-modal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="progress mb-3">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%;">75%</div>
            </div>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend" style="min-width: 50px;">
                            <div class="input-group-text text-center w-100"><i class="fa fa-user w-100" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupName" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend" style="min-width: 50px;">
                            <div class="input-group-text w-100"><i class="fa fa-envelope w-100" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupMail" placeholder="E-mail">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary w-100">button</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

!function (e, n) { "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(n) : "object" == typeof exports ? module.exports = n(require, exports, module) : e.ouibounce = n() }(this, function (e, n, o) { return function (e, n) { "use strict"; function o(e, n) { return "undefined" == typeof e ? n : e } function i(e) { var n = 24 * e * 60 * 60 * 1e3, o = new Date; return o.setTime(o.getTime() + n), "; expires=" + o.toUTCString() } function t() { s() || (L.addEventListener("mouseleave", u), L.addEventListener("mouseenter", r), L.addEventListener("keydown", c)) } function u(e) { e.clientY > k || (D = setTimeout(m, y)) } function r() { D && (clearTimeout(D), D = null) } function c(e) { g || e.metaKey && 76 === e.keyCode && (g = !0, D = setTimeout(m, y)) } function d(e, n) { return a()[e] === n } function a() { for (var e = document.cookie.split("; "), n = {}, o = e.length - 1; o >= 0; o--) { var i = e[o].split("="); n[i[0]] = i[1] } return n } function s() { return d(T, "true") && !v } function m() { s() || (e && (e.style.display = "block"), E(), f()) } function f(e) { var n = e || {}; "undefined" != typeof n.cookieExpire && (b = i(n.cookieExpire)), n.sitewide === !0 && (w = ";path=/"), "undefined" != typeof n.cookieDomain && (x = ";domain=" + n.cookieDomain), "undefined" != typeof n.cookieName && (T = n.cookieName), document.cookie = T + "=true" + b + x + w, L.removeEventListener("mouseleave", u), L.removeEventListener("mouseenter", r), L.removeEventListener("keydown", c) } var l = n || {}, v = l.aggressive || !1, k = o(l.sensitivity, 20), p = o(l.timer, 1e3), y = o(l.delay, 0), E = l.callback || function () { }, b = i(l.cookieExpire) || "", x = l.cookieDomain ? ";domain=" + l.cookieDomain : "", T = l.cookieName ? l.cookieName : "viewedOuibounceModal", w = l.sitewide === !0 ? ";path=/" : "", D = null, L = document.documentElement; setTimeout(t, p); var g = !1; return { fire: m, disable: f, isDisabled: s } } });

var _ouibounce = ouibounce(document.getElementById('ouibounce-modal'), {
    aggressive: true
});

// Hides the modal when visitor clicks outside of the modal window
$('body').on('click', function () {
    $('#ouibounce-modal').hide();
});

// Hides the modal when visitor clicks on the close / footer link
$('#ouibounce-modal .modal-footer').on('click', function () {
    $('#ouibounce-modal').hide();
});

//  jQuery stuff to keep modal window open when it's meant to
$('#ouibounce-modal .modal').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove these scripts from your JS file.

```
$('body').on('click', function () {
$('#ouibounce-modal').hide();
```

});

Comment: Then i have situation, if i click outside of the modal it dosent close, and if i insert button close in modal it dosent work, but when i call this same modal with click on button that i have on my website it works normal.

Comment: Silly me , i found that i didnt insert my button close inside modal-footer, now it works. Thank you